# Flask Application AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'todos'

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I'm trying to learn Flask by following along [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjHEcmjlD-Y).

MongoDB has been connected with the database name mydb and cluster name todos. Still, I'm getting this error:

```
File "C:\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from .main.routes import main

File "C:\routes.py", line 7, in <module>
todos_collection = mongo.db.todos

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'todos'
```

This is the file routes.py

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, redirect, url_for, request
from ..extensions import mongo
main = Blueprint('main', __name__)
todos_collection = mongo.db.todos

@main.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@main.route('/add_todo', methods=['POST'])
def add_todo():
    todo_item = request.form.get('add-todo')
    todos_collection.insert_one({'text' : todo_item, 'complete' : False})
    return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
```

This is the **init**.py file

```
from flask import Flask
from .main.routes import main
from .extensions import mongo

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb+srv://admin:<password>@cluster0.r324nzc.mongodb.net/todos'
    mongo.init_app(app)

    app.register_blueprint(main)

    return app
```

This is the extensions.py file

```
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo

mongo = PyMongo()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have missing spacing in create_app func. Try to fix it for the beginning.

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb+srv://admin:<password>@cluster0.r324nzc.mongodb.net/todos'
    mongo.init_app(app)

    app.register_blueprint(main)

    return app
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. That was an error in pasting the code here, I've changed it.